# Subsonic and SQL Azure possible?

Tags: azure-sql-database, subsonic-active-record

We're moving to Azure, I would like to ask - is it possible to use SubSonic-ActiveRecord with SQL Azure?

If so, do you know of any article with code samples and or demos showing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't done it myself, here's a [blog post](http://mongotech.blogspot.com/2010/05/threes-company-subsonic-3004-visual.html) where someone else has, and walks through the steps to do it. Note: this is about 18 months old, but should still apply (though the Windows Azure portions of the blog post are a bit dated).

Just remember that SQL Azure doesn't allow cross-database queries and doesn't provide MSDTC. As long as you're working within a single database, I believe you'll be ok.